# IndentationError: unexpected indent. Python

Tags: python

```
import sys, pyowm
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from test import Ui_Dialog

    # Crate app
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # init
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()

    # Hook Logic
    def get_weather_city():
        print( "hello wolrd" )
    ui.pushButton.clicked.connect( get_weather_city )


    # Main Loop
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

При запуске кода выдается вот такая ошибка:

```
File "C:\Users\Lios\Desktop\Project\main.py", line 6
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Я бы советовал прочитать учебник по Python. Из него вы можете узнать, что отступы в этом языке имеют значение.

Comment: вы не пробовали, все что ниже `from test import Ui_Dialog` сдвинуть влево на четыре позиции ?

Answer (score 1):

Неприятное описание ошибки, сам будучи новичком не понимал как искать решение.

На языке Python отступ означает вхождение в тело какого-то объекта, вроде класса, функции и т.п.

Вы можете написать

```
#так
def test():
    some_code_here()
    return True

test()

#или так
class ImCoder:
    def __init__(a):
        self.a = a;
```

Если вы делаете отступ там, где не обнаружена возможность войти в какое-то ограниченное пространство, возникает ошибка

> `IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Например в таком случае:

```
def func():
    print('a')
    print('b')
print('c')
    print('d') # <- здесь будет ошибка
```

Уберите все лишние отступы:

```
import sys, pyowm
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from test import Ui_Dialog

# Crate app
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

# init
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()

# Hook Logic
def get_weather_city():
    print( "hello wolrd" )
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect( get_weather_city )


# Main Loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```